# Check if insertion point is at the start or end of selection.range

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there any simple way to check if insertion point is at the start or end of `Selection.Range`?

`Selection.Collapse` collapses to start or end but not to where insertion point is.

Comment: The range of selection *IS* the insertion point.  Try it in Word.  Select a portion of text and then type a letter.  The letter should replace the whole selected range.  If you want to insert before or after the range then investigate .InsertBefore and .InsertAfter.  I'm assuming you know how to use F1 key and/or the object browser.

Comment: Maybe, I did not use the term "insertion point" correctly.

What I meant is the "last active blinker position" (for lack of better words)?

To illustrate the term "last active blinker position",
Consider the situation after a selection.range is made.
If you then hold shift + left, the selection.range is extended or contracted depending on the "last active blinker position"

I am trying to detect whether the active blinker is at the left end or right end of the selection.range.

I hope you get what I mean.
Thanks

Comment: In that case you need to check the help page for Selection.StartIsActive.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks.

Comment: @Freeflow If this is not a duplicate on the site, please post the suggestion as an Answer. If it is a duplicate, please vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The property `StartIsActive` will return whether the focus is at the beginning or the end of a selection:

```
Debug.Print Selection.StartIsActive
```

Where the focus of a selection is affects how the `Move` methods methods react when applied to a selection.

(Note that this is *not* available for `Selection.Range`, only `Selection`.)